# Stop icecast player from falling behind when paused

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, icecast, shoutcast

Is there a way that when my icecast player is paused and played it is back live rather than falling behind and playing from where it was paused?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15540186 explains how to reset playback position to zero.

In addition, You will need to employ a cache buster to make sure that the browser doesn't try to start playing back from memory, but requests the current stream. There's an answer for this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524203/2648865

Those two combined should yield the desired results.

Comment: Thank you very much I am going to look into this :)